# Remove [desktop--envoriment]

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

It's obvious typo in the tag.

I see "1 questions tagged" [here](https://askubuntu.com/tags/desktop--envoriment/info) but can't retag because I see "0 question tagged" [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/desktop--envoriment)

It has tag wiki so it'll not deleted themself as far as I know

Comment: Uhh ... What the ... Why does it even *have* a tag wiki? [Three pairs of eyes](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/131465) looked at it and no one figured something wrong? That's impressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tag has no questions, it will die automatically at 3:00 UTC when the tag cleanup scripts are run.